# e4 RCP application does not start after .exe is created with product export wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, product, rcp, e4

I tried using the export wizard in the .product of an e4 RCP application i created.
It runs fine within the IDE, but the generated .exe fails to start.

The generated log is

```
!SESSION 2023-02-15 22:45:43.801 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=17.0.6
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt 4 0 2023-02-15 22:45:44.893
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt [44]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"; bundle-version="0.16.100.v20210315-1604"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
       org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [46]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.400.v20210407-1558"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.urischeme [64]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sun.jna; bundle-version="[5.8.0,6.0.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-version="0.9.1"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-version="0.15.100.v20210515-1815"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [45]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.16.100.v20210315-1604"; singleton:="true"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1849)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1783)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1747)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 4 0 2023-02-15 22:45:44.895
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [45]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.16.100.v20210315-1604"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [46]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.400.v20210407-1558"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.urischeme [64]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sun.jna; bundle-version="[5.8.0,6.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1849)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1783)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1747)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 4 0 2023-02-15 22:45:44.896
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [46]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.400.v20210407-1558"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.urischeme [64]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sun.jna; bundle-version="[5.8.0,6.0.0)"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1849)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1783)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1747)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt 2 0 2023-02-15 22:45:45.039
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt [44]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt
    -> Export-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"; bundle-version="0.16.100.v20210315-1604"; version="0.0.0"; x-friends:="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt,org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt,org.eclipse.ui.workbench"
       org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [46]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.400.v20210407-1558"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.urischeme [64]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sun.jna; bundle-version="[5.8.0,6.0.0)"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-version="0.9.1"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt; bundle-version="0.15.100.v20210515-1815"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [45]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.16.100.v20210315-1604"; singleton:="true"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2023-02-15 22:45:45.039
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [46]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.400.v20210407-1558"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.urischeme [64]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sun.jna; bundle-version="[5.8.0,6.0.0)"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.urischeme 2 0 2023-02-15 22:45:45.040
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.urischeme [64]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sun.jna; bundle-version="[5.8.0,6.0.0)"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt 2 0 2023-02-15 22:45:45.040
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt [45]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.9.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt; bundle-version="0.16.100.v20210315-1604"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt [46]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.urischeme; bundle-version="1.1.400.v20210407-1558"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.urischeme [64]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sun.jna; bundle-version="[5.8.0,6.0.0)"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2023-02-15 22:45:45.041
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)
```

How can i fix this?

Could it be a local problem with the java installation? I removed my previously installed java 8 because java at least java 11 is required. I then installed java 17 jdk and set the env variables. But java 17 does not have a jre, so this might cause the problem? But i don't know how to solve it if thats the case.

I thought it could be missing plugins in the product so i pressed the "Add Required Plug-ins" Button, but that just makes the situation worse with the same error

Edit: After switching to a feature based product the error log changed to:

```
!SESSION 2023-02-17 17:18:49.227 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=17.0.6
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -clearPersistedState
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -clearPersistedState

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2023-02-17 17:18:50.852
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'elocalc.LifeCycle' from bundle '2'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "LifeCycle.eventBroker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.lambda$0(E4Application.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2023-02-17 17:18:50.932
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon' from bundle '48'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2023-02-17 17:18:50.937
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'elocalc.ui.handler.AddPlayerHandler' from bundle '2'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "AddPlayerHandler.eventBroker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.processActiveHandler(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.HandlerProcessingAddon.postConstruct(HandlerProcessingAddon.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2023-02-17 17:18:50.946
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.ContextProcessingAddon' from bundle '48'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "ContextProcessingAddon.broker": no actual value was found for the argument "IEventBroker".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2023-02-17 17:18:50.993
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.IThemeManager.getEngineForDisplay(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display)" because "mgr" is null
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createThemeEngine(PartRenderingEngine.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.initializeStyling(PartRenderingEngine.java:1286)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1462)
```

The application still runs fine inside the IDE

Comment: It does look like missing plug-ins or wrong versions of plug-ins.  The first error is `Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.sun.jna; bundle-version="[5.8.0,6.0.0)"` - plug-in `com.sun.jna` with a version of at least 5.8.0 and less than 6.0.0 cannot be found. You need to make sure all those plug-ins are included in the .product file. Even the simplest e4 RCP will contain over 90 plug-ins.

Comment: Note: Using a features based .product file can simplify things - in that case you just list your own feature listing your plug-ins and a small number of existing features containing the standard code - for example the `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` is enough for a "pure" e4 RCP.

Comment: Hello @greg-449, thanks for taking the time!
I checked and the version of com.sun.jna in my product was 5.8.0. It was already included.
Next i switched to a feature based product. The new product only contains org.eclipse.e4.rcp, my feature, org.eclipse.emf.ecore, org.eclipse.emf.common and my feature includes my plugin, two opcoach.e4.preferences plugins i used and because of the error with the DI i got (see Edit in Question) i again included org.eclipse.e4.core.services and org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench. So i don't know why the EventBroker can't be injected. It still runs fine in the IDE.

Comment: Another thing i'm noticing: Every time i use the export wizard, the preferenceCustomization property gets removed from my product in the org.eclipse.core.runtime.products extenstion in the plugin.xml. I used it to specify a plugin_customization.ini for preferences default values. I guess that's not the problem right now, but i assume the ini will get lost in the export, or if it's there it will not be recognized and no default values will be used from it.

Comment: The export RCP wizard is no longer supported and can be buggy. Only [tag:tycho] is supported for building RCPs. All the org.eclipse.e4 plugins are included in the org.eclipse.e4.rcp feature so should not need to be specified.

Comment: I tried to set up tycho, but i'm not quite sure how to do it. I'm following the vogella tutorial on it. It assumes you have one project named target-platform with your target definition file named target-platform.target. I don't have this so i tried to set it up. After creating a new .target and adding my feature in the locations tab the errors org.eclipse.e4.core.services and org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench could not be found showed. I wondered why as they are specified in the rcp feature in the product. And maybe this is the root of the problem. Turns out i have those two e4 plugins as ...(1/2)

Comment: Dependencies in my plugin. And as soon as i remove them from the plugin dependencies i get compile time errors. Any idea what i'm doing wrong? I set up this project two years ago and did not know that much about a correct setup so i just added the e4 plugins as dependencies in my plugin. Is this wrong? Should they just be specified via the rcp feature in the product? If yes, how can i change it so no more compile errors occure after removing the two plugins from my plugin? (2/2)

Comment: The .target file lists the Eclipse code you want to use, for the current release of Eclipse just `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-12` is enough. The .product file lists your feature and the Eclispe feature you want to use.

Comment: So for me it looks like adding them as dependencies in the plugin works inside the ide, but after the export it does not. That also would explain why it said the jna dependency is missing, because it tried to resolve it from the e4 plugins in my plugin and not from the same e4 plugins in the product where the jna was actually present.

Comment: If i specify https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-12 as software site location in the target it shows org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui; org.eclipse.linuxtools.feature.group cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable. But what do you think about the e4 features as dependencies in my plugin? Could this be the problem?

Comment: linuxtools is not part of e4, you will have to add another location to the target for it.  dependencies on e4 plug-ins in the MANIFEST.MF Require-Bundle entries is entirely normal.

Comment: Alright, so i'm trying to get the target platform to work first then. What exactly did you mean by just https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2022-12 is enough?
I used it as software site and then selected all and then the problem with linuxtools showed. But i dont use linuxtools. I don't even know what it is

Comment: Next i tried to follow the vogella tutorial on target platform which uses a similar site, but only includes eclipse platform sdk and equinox target components. But if i add just these i can't start my application because it says that org.apache.xmlgraphics is missing org.apache.comons.io, even though again, i dont use apache.xmlgraphics. Its just included in the rcp feature

Comment: I didn't know building rcp applications became a rocketscience in the meantime. Last time i used it i just pressed export and it worked. Its really frustrating to deal with this after a long time developing and not worrying about the export

Comment: Do i even need a target platform or can i just use the ide as target like before with tycho?
If i run mvn clean verify without the target platform in the tycho pom i get
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: EloCalcProduct 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: testFeature.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; EloCalc 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: EloCalcProduct 1.0.0.qualifier depends on: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; testFeature.feature.group 0.0.0

Comment: I added my plugin and my feature as modules in the pom. Is this correct?